# SQLite index decreases performance when used to locate NULL

Tags: sqlite

I observed the following phenomenon when I use SQLite in Python. Suppose there is a `table` with a few columns; its primary key is `a` and no other indices are present. I want to find the first 5 `a`'s where column `b` is NULL:

```
SELECT a FROM table WHERE b ISNULL ORDER BY a ASC LIMIT 5;
```

Running this query 1000 times takes 0.46s. Then I added an index for `b`, but running the same query 1000 times now takes 3.86s. I don't understand why in this case the index for `b` actually slows down the query. I was wondering if NULL is not indexed at all.

I repeated the same experiment by indexing both `a` and `b` rather than just `b`, and the result was 0.25s. This improvement over 0.46s seems to suggest that NULL *is* indexed (but for some reason indexing only `b` hurts). Can anyone explain this observation?

Comment: Show the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) (not EXPLAIN) in all three cases.

Answer (score -1):

How are you timing it? In Python?

Try just using an EXPLAIN statement on the query directly.

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html

Comment: Yes, in Python. The EXPLAIN outputs of all three experiments are identical, although I don't know how to interpret them.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. If you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) sufficient [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).